# Why can u'\xe5' be decoded but not '\xe5'?

Tags: python, unicode-literals

This is flabbergasting and extremely frustrating, please help.

```
>>> a1 = '\xe5'   # type <str>
>>> a2 = u'\xe5'  # type <unicode>
>>> ord(a1)
229
>>> ord(a2)
229
>>> print a2.encode('utf-8')
å
>>> print a1.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If a1 and a2 have the same value, why can't both be encoded?

I have to use an external API that returns unicode data on the `a1` form, which makes it useless. Python apparently insists that `<str>` typed strings must only contain ASCII chars or it refuses to encode them. It completely breaks my application.

Comment: Did you try decoding it using the charset it was encoded with?

Comment: Hmm... It turns out the data is encoded as latin-1. I cannot rationalize the correct guess based on any technical detail I can find. I have no idea how Python, or the terminal, or whatever, decided to use latin-1. I just made a lucky guess.

Comment: It didn't. It was encoded that way by whatever generated it.

Answer (score 3):

You can only encode Unicode strings. If you call encode on a bytestring, Python tries to *decode* it first, using the default encoding - hence the error. (Note that this confusing behaviour only occurs in Python 2, it has been removed in Python 3).

Comment: Isn't there a way to set the byte string's encoding? The data comes from a terminal that is running with LANG=en_US.utf8.

Comment: Even better: Is there no way to cast the byte string into the unicode type without running any conversion? The arrays are byte exact copies, after all.

Answer (score 1):

In `python2`, strings are ASCII, while in `python3` strings are Unicode.

ASCII characters may only have a value between 0 and 127 inclusive.
Unicode characters however may have a much higher value.

`python2`:

```py
>>> a = '\x7f'
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'\x7f'
>>> a = '\x80'
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`python3`:

```py
>>> a = '\x7f'
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
b'\x7f'
>>> a = '\x80'
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\x80'
```

The reason that this works in `python2` with the `u` prefix is because you are explicitly stating that "*this is a Unicode string*".

---

It might be worth reading up for a more in-depth understanding of using Unicode in `python2`:

- [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Overcoming frustration: Correctly using unicode in python2](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html)

---

To make use of the (broken) API, it would be best to convert the returned string into a bytearray, *but note*, this will not work in `python3`.

```py
>>> a = '\xe5'
>>> b = bytearray(a)
>>> b[0]
229
```

Remember, that `\xe5` is not a valid Unicode (UTF-8) character... To store the value `0xE5` in a [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded string, you'd need to store two bytes: `0xC3 0xA5`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tear down your confusion to pieces. Let's start first by the the distinction between `str` and `unicode`. In Python 2.X:

1. `str` is a string of 8-bit characters (1-byte) that prints as ASCII whenever possible. `str` is really a sequence of bytes and is the equivalent of `bytes` in Python 3.X. *There's no encoding for `str`.
2. `unicode` is a string of Unicode code-points.

Second, encoding means according to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#encodings):

> *"The rules for translating a Unicode string into a sequence of bytes are called an encoding."*

Then, ask yourself this question: does it makes sense to encode `str` which is already a sequence of bytes? The answer is no. Because `str` is already a sequence of bytes. It does make sense however to encode `unicode`, why? Because it's a string of Unicode character code-points (i.e, U+00E4').

Answer (score 0):

Ignacio's suggestion to decode the byte string from its actual encoding (not ascii, but what?) got me to try with latin-1 even though I think it should have been utf-8. That worked!

I get the data from the Python2.7 curses module. My best guess is the problem is in there somewhere. The terminal's encoding is utf-8, but ok it works now.